# Remove Site Info permanently from wordpress version 5.0.2

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to remove Site Info from my wordpress permanently. I am using version 5.0.2. I want to remove showing `Site Info` basically from web browser Title Bar. With every post and page it shows like-> "My post title" - "My Site Info"
Please note i already tried few things like-
`wp-content/themes/twentynineteen/template-parts/header` inside this directory i have tried to remove `<?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>` line of codes. But Site Info still shows. I am not getting idea from where this Site Info coming? And how can i stop it?
I am using default wordpress theme Twenty_Nineteen. Any idea? Please dont advice any 123 plugins. I hate plugins. I want to do it from wordpress php files

Comment: Try this: `add_filter('wp_title', function($title, $sep) { return 'CUSTOM TITLE HERE'; }, 50, 2)` if the title still shows info, then edit the `header.php` file and find the `<title>` tag, you will find the blog info being outputted there

Comment: @SaqibAmin ya but on which file and location you are mentioning to add filter?

Comment: just add the above filter in `functions.php`

Comment: No i have edited function.php and header.php both and still shows site info

Answer (score 0):

Note: If you'd like to remove site-info from Title bar, it'll be removed from the Tab at the same time.

Basically you need to remove Title Tag from functions.php file. That code is located in the 46 number line, look like this

```
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
```

And then add this hook somewhere in your functions.php

```
add_action('wp_head', function() {wp_title('');});
```

Courtesy goes to Sakib amin.

Comment: No if i remove this then Title Bar shows the domain name directly. I want show only the Post or Page title not the Site Info.

Comment: @JohnDoe after removing the above line, add this code in your theme's `functions.php` `add_action('wp_head', function() {wp_title('');});`